# Как правильно очистить интервал?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть функция которая запускает другую функцию, через равные промежутки времени но где-то после 4 запуска время начинает увеличиваться. 
Возможно нужно очистить интервал?  Но почему то не работает. После очистки интервала, функция не запускается.

Где я допускаю ошибку ?

```
   var car = 7800
   timerId = setTimeout(function tick() {

       AnimateAut()
       timerId = setTimeout(tick, car);

       clearTimeout(timerId);

   }, car);
```

Comment: 1. Как вы чистите интервал? 2. Используйте вместо `setTimeout()` `set Interval()` для периодического выполнения функций; 3. Почему после `clearTimeout(timerId)` нет точки с запятой?; 4. Для чего строка `timerId` после нее?

Comment: @tutankhamun, Как должна выглядеть запись такой функции через set Interval() ?

Comment: @Dementiy1999 тоже самое, только вместо `setTimeout` - `setInterval`

Comment: В вашем случае `timerId = setInterval(AnimateAut, car);` И учтите, что интервалы в `setTImeout()` и `setInterval()` могут увеличиваться прри большой нагрузке на браузер

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы устанавливаете таймер и тут же его очищаете, в этом и ошибка. Предполагаю что такая конструкция будет рабоатать верно (устанавливаете новый таймер только после завершения предыдущего):

```
var car = 7800;
function tick() {
   AnimateAut();
   setTimeout(tick, car);
}

setTimeout(tick, car);
```

Answer (score 1):

Хотелось бы также упомянуть специально разработанную(но не вошедшую в стандарт) функцию - [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/DOM/window.requestAnimationFrame).

Её преимущество в том, что время до перерисовки следующего кадра рассчитывается автоматически исходя из загруженности браузера, активности вкладки и тд, и тп.

```js
// polifill
(function() {
  var requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame 
   || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame 
   || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame 
   || window.msRequestAnimationFrame;
  window.requestAnimationFrame = requestAnimationFrame;
})();

let start = window.performance.now();
function rotation(el, T = 333, R = 100) {
  let stop; 
  let style = window.getComputedStyle(el);
  let startX = parseFloat(style.left || 0);
  let startY = parseFloat(style.top || 0);
  const step = ts => {
    let t = ts - start;
    let x = Math.cos(t/T)*R + startX;
    let y = Math.sin(t/T)*R + startY;

    el.style.left = x + "px";
    el.style.top = y + "px";
    if (!stop)
     requestAnimationFrame(step);
  };
  requestAnimationFrame(step);
  return ()=>stop=true;
}
let stopFn = rotation(document.querySelector('ball'));
setTimeout(stopFn, 12000);
```

```css
ball{
  background-color: silver;
  border-radius: 100%;
  left: 100px;
  top: 100px;
  width: 5vw;
  height: 5vw;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<ball></ball>
```

Answer (score -1):

AngularJS Прекрасно работающий вариант

```
var promise;
vm.start = function() {
    promise = $interval(setUnlocked, 60000);
};
// stops the interval
vm.stop = function() {
    $interval.cancel(promise);
};
// starting the interval by default
vm.start();

function setUnlocked() {
    vm.stop();
}
```

Comment: А кто-то просил AngularJS?

Comment: Специально для фанатов. Ну главное идея а не язык